# c# system.data.oledb.oledbexeption индекс не найден

Tags: c#, индексы, dbf

При попытке выполнить запрос выдает ошибку - индекс не найден.
По указанному пути лежит otdel.cdx и otdel.dbf. Таблица сформирована в FoxPro.

```
            try
        {
            if (textBoxCard.Text != "")
            {
                string connectionString = "Provider =Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + pathStr + "; Extended Properties = dBASE IV; User ID = Admin; Password =; ";
                
                using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    //string queryUpdate = "create table otdel(newcard_n varchar(12), tab_nom varchar(10))";
                    string queryUpdate = "update otdel set newcard_n='" + textBoxCard.Text + "' where tab_nom='" + textBoxTab.Text + "'";

                    OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                    command = connection.CreateCommand();
                    command.CommandText = queryUpdate;
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    connection.Close();
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Данные записаны!", "Успешно");
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Не найдено записей по табельному номеру!", "Ошибка");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n\n" + ex.ToString());
        }
```

Сбоит на command.ExecuteNonQuery().
Пробовал создать таблицу(закомментированная create), после чего обновить ее, все работает. А готовую таблицу из FoxPro обновлять не хочет.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: используйте Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro 8.0

Comment: @Konst программа работает на Win x64. На сколько я знаю, на нем не работает VFPOLEDB.

Comment: тогда используйте ODBC драйвер

Comment: @Konst а можно пример connectionString, а то не совсем понимаю как подключиться к VFP таблице через ODBC

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/dbf-foxpro/

Comment: Provider=MSDASQL.1;Extended Properties="DefaultDir=C:\MyDBaseFolder;Driver={Microsoft dBase Driver (*.dbf)};DriverId=277;"

Provider=MSDASQL.1;Data Source=DBF_DATA;Extended Properties="DSN=DBF_DATA;DefaultDir=C:\MyDBaseFolder;DriverId=533;FIL=dBase 5.0;"   2 варианта, один через созданный DSN

Comment: @Konst сделал через ODBC, ошибка та же - индекс не найден... Как только удаляю .cdx все работает, а с ним - никак

Comment: как видно индекс может использовать только родной драйвер Visual FoxPro. если индекс вам не принципиален, то удаляйте все лишние файлы из каталога , кроме самих dbf.

Comment: @Konst спасибо за помощь, видимо удалять индексный файл, единственный выход